# Application-defined or object defined error - Can't find the answer

Tags: vba

I have searched all over but cannot figure this out. All I want is for the program to check if the 6th character of the string is equal to "C", and if so, make the cell's font red. I have tried several different fixes (this wasn't my first code) but cannot figure out why I keep getting this error. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

```
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim Content As String

Worksheets("Data").Activate
Rows = Worksheets("Data").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

For x = 1 To Rows
Content = Mid(Cells(x, "A"), 6, 1)

If Content = "C" Then
    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Range(Cells(x, "A")).Font.Color = vbRed  <---- ERROR
    End With
End If
Next x
```

Comment: `.Cells(x, "A").Font.Color = vbRed`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the word `Range` and it should work.  You can also just use `.Range("A" & x).Font.Color = vbRed` just for future reference.